# segmentation fault in fork()

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, udp, fork

I am running into some problems while I am trying to do a multi-process program in a Raspberry Pi. 
There are only two processes: one to read data from an Analog to Digital converter and another process which receives this data via a pipe and sends it to a PC via a UDP protocol. 
Both programs have been tested individually and they work just fine, the problema I am running into is that when trying to execute them via a multi-process program I have a Segmentation fault error which does not let me créate my two processes. The error appears when calling the fork() function.

This is the code I am trying to make work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "ADS1256_DAC8532_lib.h"
#include "addstrings2.h"
#include "changetypes.h"
#include "ReadWriteSock.h"
#include "Socket.h"



int main(){
//Variables for the first program: reading the ADC
int32_t adc[3];
uint8_t ch_num;
//variables for the UDP protocol program
struct sockaddr_in Directionwrite;
int Descriptor,aux;
struct sockaddr_in Recv;
int RecvAddrSize=sizeof(Recv);

//General variables that are needed in all our programs

int variable;
float *servo=0;
float *pressure1=0;
float *position=0;
float *pressure2=0;
char SendDataADC[11];
char press1[5];
char press2[5];
char pos[5];
char cservo[5];
int ppres1[2];
int ppres2[2];
int ppos[2];
int pservo [2];
pipe(ppres1);
pipe(ppres2);
pipe(ppos);
pipe(pservo);
if(fork()){
    //Father process
            bcm2835_init();
            bcm2835_spi_begin();
            bcm2835_spi_setBitOrder(BCM2835_SPI_BIT_ORDER_LSBFIRST );      // The default
            bcm2835_spi_setDataMode(BCM2835_SPI_MODE1);                   // The default
            bcm2835_spi_setClockDivider(BCM2835_SPI_CLOCK_DIVIDER_8192); // The default
            bcm2835_gpio_fsel(SPICS, BCM2835_GPIO_FSEL_OUTP);//
            bcm2835_gpio_write(SPICS, HIGH);
            bcm2835_gpio_fsel(DRDY, BCM2835_GPIO_FSEL_INPT);
            bcm2835_gpio_set_pud(DRDY, BCM2835_GPIO_PUD_UP); 

            ADS1256_CfgADC(ADS1256_GAIN_1, ADS1256_15SPS);
            ADS1256_StartScan(1);
            ch_num=3;
            while(1){
                while((ADS1256_Scan() == 0));
                for (unsigned int i = 0; i < ch_num; i++){
                    adc[i] = ADS1256_GetAdc(i);
                    adc[i] = (adc[i] * 100) / 167;  
                    switch(i){
                        case 0:
                                    *position=adc[i]<<2;
                                    passtochar(*position,pos);
                                    write(ppos[1],pos,4);
                                     break;    //We multiply the ADC value of our position sensor by 4 beacuse we are going to have an electronical circuit that is going to amplify our signal by a factor of 0.25 so it can be read by our Rpi  
                        case 1: 
                                *pressure1=adc[i]; 
                                passtochar(*pressure1,press1);
                                write(ppres1[1],press1,4);
                                break;     //The pressure sensors do not need to be a,plified i order to be read, thay are only going to have a filter to reduce the amount of noise read
                        case 2:
                            *pressure2=adc[i];
                            passtochar(*pressure2,press2);
                            write(ppres2[1],press2,4);
                             break;
                        default: break;
                    }
                }
                    read(pservo[0],cservo,4);
                    *servo=passtofloat(cservo);
                    *servo=*servo/8;    //Si c'est entre -10 et 10 le voltage au servo, on le regle pour 0 20 et apres on l'adjustera avec un circuit electronique. 20/4 sont 5v, notre limite(trop juste, et le programme peut faire erreurs de precision), on utilise 8 pour être secures.
                    Write_DAC8552(0x30, Voltage_Convert(5.0, *servo));
               //printf("Bucle de ADC \r\n");
               usleep(1000);
           }
           bcm2835_spi_end();
           bcm2835_close();
            }
    else{   
    //Child process
            Directionwrite.sin_family = AF_INET;
            Directionwrite.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr("169.254.51.37");
            Directionwrite.sin_port = htons(59212);

                Descriptor = socket (AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
                printf("\n Llego");
                aux=connect(Descriptor, (struct sockaddr *)&Directionwrite, sizeof (Directionwrite));
                            printf("\n aux=%d, aux);
            while(1){
                printf("Dentro del bucle socket");
                read(ppres1[0],press1,4);
                read(ppres2[0],press2,4);
                read(ppos[0],ppos,4);
                write(pservo[1],cservo,4);
                addstringsADCv2(SendDataADC,press1,press2,pos);
                writeSocket(Descriptor,SendDataADC,strlen(SendDataADC));
                //int b=readSocket(Descriptor,servo,5);
                int b=recvfrom(Descriptor, cservo,5,0,(struct sockaddr *) &Recv, &RecvAddrSize);
                cservo[4]='\0';
                write(pservo[1],cservo,4);
                printf("\n %d", b);
                printf("\n Hemos recibido el valor: %s", cservo);
                }
            }              
        }
return 0;
```

}

As for some of the functions that are called in the program, passtochar is a function that I have created which asks for two parameters(float value and a char vector) and it converts the float value into ASCII and stores it into the vector. 
As for the function addstringsADCv2 it just gets several char vectors and place them into one which is bigger.
Thanks in advance for any posible help.

Comment: Number one would be not to write `if(fork()) { /* wall of code */ }  else { /* wall of code */ }` but to use functions. Number zero would be not to use fork() in the first place, since it's such a dysfunctional API... but then most of Linux is. Is there a reason why you can't use threads instead?

Comment: `read(ppos[0],ppos,4);` will overwrite the file descriptor in `ppos[0]`.

Comment: @Lundin to be honest there is no reason, it is just that I do not know how to work with them. I am going to do some research and try to use them and I will post it here if there is any type of answer.

Comment: @sebs pthreads are far more programmer-friendly to work with than fork(), that's for sure. And overall far more modern - in most of the cases it doesn't make sense to spawn a whole new process when all you actually need is multi-tasking.

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.  2) consistently indent the code.  Indent after every opening brace '{'. Unindent before every closing brace '}.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces.

Comment: the `fork()` function has three return types: 1) greater than 0 means successful and in the parent process.  2) equal 0 means in successful and in the child process.  3) less than 0 means failure (and still in the parent process)  So the code is incorrectly using that function.

Comment: the posted code is using several 'home grown' header files, but the contents of those files is not posted, so we cannot re-create your problem.  Please post a [mcve] so we can (more easily) help you.